# How to fill a field until it reaches the length of the field SQL

Tags: sql, database, string

I have a field that is 11 in length, what happens in this field is that when the entered data does not reach 11, we must fill the rest with 0, for example we enter the data "CARLOS", then in the database it should look like this "00000CARLOS"

Comment: `LPAD('CARLOS',11,'0')`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Tables have a _columns_, not a fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lpad()`:

```
lpad(mycol, 11, '0')
```

This function is supported in both MySQL and Oracle (you initially tagged both), with the same syntax.